# Calling ADF page Custom Listener (Ex: ActionListener) from BPM Process Task (APPROVE/REJECT)

Tags: process, business-process-management

Jdeveloper version - 11.1.1.7

I am very new to BPM / SOA development, but I have very good development skills on ADF.

I am not using ADF BC, using EJB for business services and also using custom ADF pages for HumanTasks.

Usecase:

From the BPM Process task, when process submission (APPROVE / REJECT) , I need to invoke a Custom listener (Ex.Action Listener - a EJB call) in the ADF page.

I am trying to use BPM APIs.

Please clarify me how this will achieve using BPM APIs. I need detail guidelines to do it. Please make to understand this process.

---

Provide some useful documentation or links to understand the following:

1. Custom Human task pages
2. BPM APIs - 11.1.1.7
3. Call a BPM process task from ADF Listener and Call a ADF Listener from BPM Process task - Using BPM APIs.

Please revert more clarifications needed.

Thanks and Regards

Mohanraj N

Answer (score 2):

1. JDeveloper has special project type for BPM Human Tasks. See documentation - docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/dev.1111/e10224/bp_tutorialhwf_.htm#BABBBDHI
2. [Oracle Fusion Middleware Java API Reference for Oracle BPM Suite](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/apirefs.1111/e25378/toc.htm). Useful [examples](http://soadev.blogspot.ru/search/label/BPM) of using BPM API. Custom BPM client - redstack.wordpress.com/tag/worklist/ developed with Spring MVC
3. Call a ADF Listener from BPM Process task using bindings on Human task form - client www.avioconsulting.com/blog/updating-bpm-11g-xml-payload-adf

Sorry, because of low reputation can't provide more than 2 link